# where is blender shader library UI?

Tags: materials, interface

i am cinema4d and keyshot user and i wanted try blender
but i have a problem/confusion in blender

i am not talking about node editor for shader.

in cinema i have library and shader presets that i have saved over the years, when i want i can browse and add them to project and i can see what i have in the project and drag them to my objects

cinema4d ui [image: https://ibb.co/kBVVhpF]

PROBLEM

i cant locate where the shader library UI is?
where is all the shaders added to project?

thanks in advance
please show me images if possible

edit 1 : latest beta 2.8

Comment: Hey there. There isn't one as such, yet. What version of Blender are you using? You could try this addon https://blenderartists.org/t/simple-asset-manager-2-8/1134084.
There are others if you search.

Comment: cegaton done, Tilmah im on 2.8 i will try that thanks

Comment: 2.80 includes a new addon called [blenderkit](https://www.blenderkit.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender's shaders can be found in the Properties Editor, Material tab, Material drop down menu:

[image]

It's easy to navigate them because you can start typing the name of the material just after clicking it to search. If you wish to keep the material without assigning it to anything you will need to press the F icon next to the material's name to assign a fake user for it not to get removed when you reload the scene. It's a shield icon in Blender 2.80:

[image]

That's about it. You might also find it useful to know the shortcut for linking materials to multiple objects when working with materials. If you have multiple objects selected and assign materials to the last one(active), you can hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> followed by <kbd>m</kbd> to link materials to all the selected objects.

Coming from another software package this is often a huge shock, however once/if you get used to this way of thinking about materials in the scene you might find it surprisingly convenient and easy to use.

There are some useful functions in the Outliner, Blender File mode as well. You can select objects linked to specific material there as well as delete materials and do some other useful things:

[image]

Comment: thank you, it is very helpfull

Comment: one more thing. is there a plan for blender dev team to add library features like in cinema4d?

Comment: I have seen talks about some sort of asset manager. It might happen.There are plans to improve functionality of the Outliner as well, it may get more material-library-like features, but those are only guesses. My own experience is: coming from years with Maya I was really shocked there was nothing like that in Blender, but when I got used to it I was surprised, how I don't miss it and I am quite happy there is one less editor to worry about while my workflows are fine without it. I would recommend trying Blender's way first, see how it goes, but there are many add-ons for that as well.

Comment: thank you martin, i hope they do consider making a UI for people that didnt used 3d software before, i do remember when i was starting why i choose Cinema4d it was easy UI :)

Answer (score 0):

There something like that in Blender 2.79 internal render that am using.

Goto>File>Preferences>Add-on
Then activate "Material Library"

Then go to Object Material Property Tab, You will see the Material Library.

In that Material Library, choose the Render Engine, the Materials for the Selected Engine will be listed.

Screenshots coming soon